# How to ensure that the data read from QLocalSocket is in correct sequence/size/periodicity?

Tags: qt, qt5, ipc

I have a `QWidget` that hold a `QProcess`, the widget communicate will the sub-process by `QLocalServer`/`QLocalSocket`.

To simplify the question, let's say the program run in sub-process owned by the widget will write an integer(4 byte) through `QLocalSocket` at any time.

The widget that hold the sub-process connect itself with the process by the `readyRead` signal

```
localSocket = localServer->nextPendingConnection();

connect(localSocket, &QLocalSocket::readyRead, this, &StationWidget::onChildProcessSignal);
```

However, in the function `onChildProcessSignal`, i find that i cannot make any assumption on the sequence that i've read through the socket, the `byteAvailable` can range from 4 to 20.

I've tried to immediately call `QLocalSocket::flush` after `QLocalSocket::write`, however, it seems that it has nothing to help with the situation(windows system).

So, what methods should i use to ensure that the data are come in sequential and each packet are 4 byte at a time. Could other IPC techniques do better?

Comment: "However, in the function onChildProcessSignal, i find that i cannot make any assumption on the sequence that i've read through the socket, the byteAvailable can range from 4 to 20." - Because that's how sequential devices works :) Data can come in parts and you never know when and how much. You should use this in your signal: `while(socket->bytesAvailable() >= 4){ socket->read(4);}`

Comment: @Macias, if i use other IPC method, for example, TCP, can i make assumption that in most situation, the data can come 4 byte each time?

Comment: No, TCP is stream oriented too. Same situation. If you have both processes on the same machine, there is no need to use TCP - QLocalSocket is fine. Just read by 4 bytes in loop. If there is not enough bytes -wait for next readyRead signal and then read.

Comment: @Macias what about udp? Or any other IPC techniques?

Comment: `UDP (User Datagram Protocol) is a lightweight, unreliable, datagram-oriented` -  Yes, you always get whole datagrams, but not necessarily in order and UDP does not guarantee that your packets will arrive